# Continuous subfigure numbering

Tags: floats, numbering, subfloats

I have a lot of files including images and I want them to be numbered continuously.

I use many images next to each other, which looks like

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[bla]{bla1.jpg}
            \caption{bla}
            \label{fig:bla1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[bla]{bla2.jpg}
            \caption{bla}
            \label{fig:bla2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Their caption labels are (1) and (2).

Then I have single images like:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{0.62\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[bla]{bla3.jpg}
    \caption{bla}
    \label{fig:bla3}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Its label is (1) again, but I would like it to have (3).

My attempt was to use:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{subfigure}{figure}
```

so that it ignores the figure-environment. It does not work.

The problem is that I am using memoir as `documentclass`, without using chapters. Originally, the pictures were numbered continuously like 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc., because they were in `minipages` instead of `subfigures`. But I wanted to remove the `0`, so that I replaced the `minipages` with `subfigures` and

```
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{subfigure}}
```

I hope this is understandable and I appreciate your help!

Comment: What about DCs 'remreset'?

Comment: What about `\ContinuedFloat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution using the `etoolbox` package and a new counter which will be increased by one each time the `subfigure` environment is called.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{fignumber}
\setcounter{fignumber}{0}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{fignumber}}

\AtBeginEnvironment{subfigure}{\refstepcounter{fignumber}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{bla1.jpg}
            \caption{bla}
            \label{fig:bla1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{bla2.jpg}
            \caption{bla}
            \label{fig:bla2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{0.62\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{bla3.jpg}
    \caption{bla}
    \label{fig:bla3}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT** It turned out that the above solution is not entirely satisfying when calling `\ref{}` with one of the labels defined (see this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134425/31058)). In order to fix that, just add these lines to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem! Unluckily I have a follow-up problem concerning the referencing of the subfigures, if anybody is interested:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134425/referencing-of-subfigures-is-wrong