# Referencing of subfigures is wrong

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, subfloats

After Ludovic C. solved my last problem

[Continuous subfigure numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134398/continous-subfigure-numbering)

I have another problem relating to the numbering of subfigures.

When I reference a picture with the number (1) like this

```
\ref{fig:bla1}
```

I get Fig. 011 instead of Fig. 1. I guess it has something to do with the solution for my numbering of subfigures (see link above)!

Maybe it is Fig. "chapter""figure""subfigure", but I am not sure. And it would be great to know how to change it to just "subfigure"! This is my first time using Latex and I am trying my best to use google etc., but I cannot find a solution to this. It seems to be too unique of a problem.

Thank you very much for your efforts :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding these lines to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{}
\makeatother
```

In my case it works.

**NOTE** If you want I can even edit my answer to your previous question to add this feature.

Comment: And thanks again, I appreciate your help! This is the solution.