# Remove chapter prefix from subfigure references

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, subfloats

my institute requires continuous numbering of figures. Therefore I use the **chngcntr** package.
Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for subfigures.
I'd like to have something like "see figure 1(a)" instead of "1.1(a)".
I already tried some things (including [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134425/referencing-of-subfigures-is-wrong)) but was not successful.

[image]

So far, this is my mininmal environment code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
%\counterwithout{subfigure}{section}  %This doesn't work either

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}

Some text where I refer to subfigure 1~(see figure~\ref{fig:one}).\\
Some other text where I refer to subfigure 2~(see figure~\ref{fig:two}).\\
Even more text where I refer to the whole figure~(see figure~\ref{fig:biglabel}).

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \subfigure[First Caption]{\label{fig:one}
    \rule{3cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
    }
    \subfigure[Second Caption]{\label{fig:two}
    \rule{3cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
    }
    \caption{Big Caption}
    \label{fig:biglabel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the `subfigure` package is considered obsolete, you might want to switch to either `subfig` or `subcaption`.

Comment: @leandriis It was quite some work to switch to subcaption but now it works, thank you!